# How to Use ssh-keygen Generated SSH Key with SourceTree for Azure DevOps Repo

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, atlassian-sourcetree, ssh-keygen

I've encountered a challenge while trying to connect (clone) to my Azure DevOps repository via SourceTree.

1 - I used the PowerShell command ssh-keygen to generate an SSH key on my computer. The command generated two files in my selected folder: one for the private key that has no extension, and one for the public key with a .pub extension.
The public key starts with

ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EA....

, and the private key file is in the expected format, starting with

-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
and ending with -----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----.

However, SourceTree seems to only accept Putty (.ppk) keys, and my keys generated by ssh-keygen don't meet that criteria.

I attempted to use these SSH keys with SourceTree by going to

"Tools > Import SSH Keys,"

but SourceTree did not recognize my key files. It appears that SourceTree is looking for keys in the .ppk format, which I don't have.

Is there a way to convert the SSH key from ssh-keygen to a format that SourceTree accepts, or should I generate new keys in a compatible format?

I'm seeking guidance on how to proceed so I can use SourceTree to manage my Azure DevOps repository using SSH keys.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: See [this question](https://superuser.com/q/912304/1856907) on SuperUser, the answers have both GUI and commandline solutions you can try.

Comment: Thanks @Hugo, even that does not solved my question but pointed me more deep to understand the ssh authentication. I Marked the wade-zhou-msft as the correct answer because it nailed the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the `SSH Client configuration` on sourcetree from `PuTTY/Plink` to `OpenSSH` to use the keys generated from powershell.

Steps as below：

1. Generate the keys from powershell:
   [image]
2. On SoureTree -> Tools -> Options -> General tab, change to `OpenSSH`, select the isa key generated above -> click ok to save.

[image]

3. open the public key file(.pub), copy the content, and input it to DevOps.
   [image]
4. On DevOps repo, copy the `SSH` URL and paste to sourcetree.

[image]

In addition, if you encounter some connection error on sourcetree, change to use embedded git for a try.

[image]